# Parsing xml with Jquery and getting errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, rss

I am trying to parse an xml feed source using the following piece of code:

```
<script>      
    $.get('http://...', function (data) {
        $(data).find("entry").each(function () { // or "item" or whatever suits your feed
            var el = $(this);

            console.log("------------------------");
            console.log("title      : " + el.find("title").text());
            console.log("author     : " + el.find("author").text());
            console.log("description: " + el.find("description").text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Note:** when I replace `"http://..."` with any xml rss source, I get an error saying:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

when I change the http to https I still get the following error in console:

> GET https:... net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

1. How Can I make a secure connection.....
2. Is there a better way to parse xml feeds using javascript or Jquery(I dont want to use PHP or any other...). Initially I used google Api to parse the feeds but that API is not supported any more "https://developers.google.com/feed/" do you know any other APIs/libraries to parse feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.parseXML(data)` instead of `$(data)` like:

```
$.get('http://...', function (data) {
    $.parseXML(data).find("entry").each(function () { 
         //...
    });
});
```